# How must Teamcity be configured to work withtout SVC?

Tags: configuration, teamcity

I am new in Teamcity and I created a Build, with a RunScript step.

I changed nothing in the source control configuration of this step.

The goal of the Build step is to run a script nothing else.

When running the build, Teamcity tries to do a source checkout (not configured) and stays blocked there.

What is the correct Teamcity SVC configuration in order that the build works even when SVC is not configured? Is it even possible or I should configure a fake SVC system like GIT to get it running?

[image]

Comment: How did you install the Teamcity build agent? Have you tried to install only the agent without the servce?

Comment: You install it! ;OP, But the solution is as interactive agent, not as Service

Comment: I figured that out as well by myself. You could add this as an answer and accept it as the solution. Which I would upvote because it worked for me as well ;-)

Comment: I documented the answer so it is better readable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Teamcity, as with TFS, when you want to handle UI Tests, you should install the Test Agents as Interactive and not as Service.

If you Install them as Services, you will not have access to all the functionalities you need for UI testing.